# Redirect a PHP website path to Node website

Tags: php, node.js, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a php website(example.com) and node website running at localhost:8888. I need to forward all request coming to redirect all requests coming at example.com/newpath to my node website. I tried

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com/path
    ServerAlias www.example.com/path

    ProxyRequests off

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location />
        ProxyPass http://localhost:8888/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8888/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

This works perfectly for subdomains. So if there is any way to get this done. Please help me. 
Sorry for my poor English. Thanks

Comment: I think you need the "path" element to be in Location, not ServerName sections. So, "ServerName example.com" and <Location /path>

Comment: If you wanna redirect all request coming for example.com/path to your localhost:8888 running in the same server then add  `Redirect 301 /path http://localhost:8888` just below your `ServerName example.com/path` and restart the apache